# Drupal 7 node_save() causes AJAX to fail

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I've created custom node form with only two fields attached. Each field have own "Save" AJAX button. On "Save" button click, everything goes as if it is default node form submission. Here is the full code:

```
/**
 * Form;
 */
function mymodule_custom_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $node = node_load(123);
  $node->langcode = entity_language('node', $node);

  // Store node object in form state
  if (!isset($form_state['node'])) {
    if (!isset($node->title)) {
      $node->title = NULL;
    }
    node_object_prepare($node);
    $form_state['node'] = $node;
  }
  else {
    $node = $form_state['node'];
  }

  // Basic node information.
  // These elements are just values so they are not even sent to the client.
  $properties = array('nid', 'vid', 'uid', 'created', 'type', 'language');
  foreach ($properties as $key) {
    $form[$key] = array(
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#value' => isset($node->$key) ? $node->$key : NULL,
    );
  }

  // Changed must be sent to the client, for later overwrite error checking.
  $form['changed'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#default_value' => isset($node->changed) ? $node->changed : NULL,
  );

  // TEST 1 field
  field_attach_form('node', $node, $form, $form_state, $node->langcode, array(
    'field_name' => 'field_test_1'
  ));

  // Set the form prefix and suffix to support AJAX
  $form['field_test_1']['#prefix'] = '<div id="wrapper-field-test-1">';
  $form['field_test_1']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  // the submit button
  $form['field_test_1']['save'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
    '#name' => 'button-field-test-1',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_custom_form_ajax_submit',
      'wrapper' => 'wrapper-field-test-1',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    )
  );

  // TEST 2 field
  field_attach_form('node', $node, $form, $form_state, $node->langcode, array(
    'field_name' => 'field_test_2'
  ));

  // Set the form prefix and suffix to support AJAX
  $form['field_test_2']['#prefix'] = '<div id="wrapper-field-test-2">';
  $form['field_test_2']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  // the submit button
  $form['field_test_2']['save'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
    '#name' => 'button-field-test-2',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_custom_form_ajax_submit',
      'wrapper' => 'wrapper-field-test-2',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    )
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Form validate;
 */
function mymodule_custom_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $field_name = reset($form_state['triggering_element']['#parents']);

  // Validate only the stuff we need
  $fields = array(
    'field_test_1',
    'field_test_2'
  );
  foreach ($fields as $field => $bundle) {
    if ($field_name != $field) {
      unset($form_state['values'][$field], $form_state['input'][$field]);
    }
  }

  // $form_state['node'] contains the actual entity being edited, but we must
  // not update it with form values that have not yet been validated, so we
  // create a pseudo-entity to use during validation.
  $node = (object) $form_state['values'];
  node_validate($node, $form, $form_state);
  entity_form_field_validate('node', $form, $form_state);
}

/**
 * Form submit;
 */
function mymodule_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Execute all submit functions
  $node = $form_state['node'];
  entity_form_submit_build_entity('node', $node, $form, $form_state);

  node_submit($node);
  foreach (module_implements('node_submit') as $module) {
    $function = $module . '_node_submit';
    $function($node, $form, $form_state);
  }

  // Save the node
  node_save($node);

  $form_state['values']['nid'] = $node->nid;
  $form_state['nid'] = $node->nid;
}

/**
 * Form ajax submit;
 */
function mymodule_custom_form_ajax_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $field_name = reset($form_state['triggering_element']['#parents']);

  // validate the form
  drupal_validate_form('mymodule_custom_form', $form, $form_state);
  // if there are errors, return the form to display the error messages
  if (form_get_errors()) {
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    return $form[$field_name];
  }
  // process the form
  mymodule_custom_form_submit($form, $form_state);

  // Show the processing box
  $form[$field_name] = array('#markup' => 'Thanks!');
  $form[$field_name]['#prefix'] = '<div id="wrapper-' . str_replace('_', '-', $field_name) . '">';
  $form[$field_name]['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  // return the confirmation message
  return $form[$field_name];
}
```

The code works perfectly, except that `node_save($node)` causes `The content on this page has either been modified by another user, or you have already submitted modifications using this form. As a result, your changes cannot be saved.` error.

No errors, if I remove it. But I need to save node and trigger all the hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue caused by this line :

```
 // process the form
 mymodule_custom_form_submit($form, $form_state);
```

in your ajax function, try to use the node_save into your ajax function.  mymodule_custom_form_submit is the conventional hook usually used. It seems to be several save process at the same time.

Comment: It didn't help. My wild guess is that, while the form builds first time, all `field_attach_form ` calls use `$node` object which is updated after first submit. This update could cause already attached fields to become old?

Comment: I think yes , so try to comment some line and debug to identify which process makes your issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've solved it or not, but I've been stuck in a similar situation.

I avoid the error: *The content on this page has either been modified...*, modifying *changed* value in `$form_state`. In your submit function: `mymodule_custom_form_submit`, **right after** `node_save($node)`, Add this line:

```
$form_state['input']['changed'] = $node->changed;
```

Answer (score -1):

Drupal 7 full Save & Stay callback function, please add wrapper for form:

```
function <MODULE_NAME>_node_ajax_save_callback($form, &$form_state){

  // If error, return form.
  if (form_get_errors()) {
    return $form;
  }

  node_form_submit($form, $form_state);
  $form['changed']['#value'] = $form_state['node']->changed;

  return $form;
}
```